# Finding the Rate of Decrease to End Up at Goal Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I'm trying to find the Rate of decrease at which 1,262 is multiplied by every day (16 times in total) and added to the Base number of 17,584 in total 16 times to get to the goal number of 24,000. I've started to work out a formula but I know I'm way off.

$24,000=17,584+(1,262\times R)^{16}$

Here's my question phrased as an example: I've spent 17,584   ℎ ℎ. ,   1,262. I need to lower my daily spend by R each day for the next 16 days to end up spending $24,000 total.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: square roots undo squares, so...

Comment: Does the base number increase during the 16 days? If not, then your equation is right. Start by subtracting $17,584$ 44

Comment: Ignore - I misread the question.

Comment: @callculus42 the base number increases during the 16 days. It would increase every day. Here's my question phrased as an example: I've spent $17,584 so far this month. Yesterday, I spent $1,262. I need to lower my daily spend by R each day for the next 16 days to end up spending $24,000 total.

Comment: @Makayla As far as I've understood it the equation must be $24000=17584+1262\cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} (1+R)^{i}$. I get approximately $R=-0.19=-19\%$.

Comment: @Makayla Did my comment helped?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you are effectively looking for, is a geometric series with $t_0=1262$, and $r$ such that $t_{16}=24000 - 17584=6416$. There are several ways to do this: use the initial formula for a geometric series and solve for $r$, or use one of the rearranged formulae to obtain $r$ directly.

If the first of the remaining sixteen days is allowed 1262 currency expenditure as well, you can adjust this.

Your equation will not work for this purpose. You are instead calculating something that makes no sense in this context.

If you instead removed the brackets, you would be finding an $R$ that provides no further information than what rate to decrease the initial spending by, each day, so that you could spend all of the remaining money on the last day only (and not daily as you need).

A brief check with Excel gives back $r=0.845$ as getting you within a single unit's accuracy, which for real expenditure, is as good as you are likely to need. That is, reduce each day's spending by 15.5% compared to the day before.

Comment: Hi @Nij, this answer makes sense. I'm having a hard time finding the formula that can be used. I've tried the following:

24000=17584+1262(r)^(16-1)

Comment: I've also tried 6416=(1262[1-r^(16)])/(1-r) but I'm not sure how to solve for R or If it's possible.

Comment: Solving your second formula for r is what you need. That first one will give nothing useful.

Comment: I get r = ~0.81. How did you get  =0.845? That seems to be correct when I plug and play in excel.

Comment: @Makayla Have you noticed that $1-0.81=0.19=19\%$, what I got. So the decreasing factor is $0.81$ and the decreasing rate is  $-0.19$

Comment: You are using 1262 as the first daily expenditure in your remaining sixteen days, which means a greater reduction is needed in the other fifteen. If you instead use 1262 as day zero, and all sixteen days have the reduction applied, you don't need to have such a large reduction. @Makayla

Comment: Thank you! This is a really helpful explanation.